# Google OAuth2 does not work with Amazon EC2 instance's public DNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, google-oauth

## Background

I have an EC2 instance hosting a website. The website uses Google's OAuth2 API for validation (aka Google Identity Platform).

The instance has a public DNS something like `http://ec2-99-99-99-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com`.

That url is added to the 'Authorized JavaScript origins' section in the Credential management portal.

Going back to the client side, users authenticate using the Google Login button widget.

## The Problem

The google widget fails when it tries to list the different login options. For fresh logins it looks like this:
[image: Google Widget Failure]

Examining the network panel reveals this call fails:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc?action=listSessions&client_id=...&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-99-99-99-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com&scope=openid%20profile%20email&ss_domain=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-99-99-99-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com

{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain."
}
```

## Investigation Notes

- It is not an SSL issue as other urls like `http://localhost:9000` work fine.
- It is not an issue with the `redirect_uri` because other urls work fine with out it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that, for whatever reason, Google specifically does not like the default instance urls constructed by amazon.

Our solution was to use a new custom domain pointing to our ec2 instance like: `http://something.anotherdomain.com`.